# Svelte and Sapper: slide with hidden element

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, svelte, sapper

With Svelte, I want to setup a slide toggle element with svelte transition.

But I also want the default not visible text to be rendered on server side for SEO.

So I end up with this trick:

```html
<script>
  import { slide } from 'svelte/transition';

  export let title;
  // We need to combine visible and hidden to make sure the text is rendered on SSR calls.
  export let visible = true;
  export let hidden = true;

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    visible = false;
    hidden = false;
  }
</script>

<div class="border mb-6">
  <div
    class="p-6 select-none cursor-pointer flex items-center"
    on:click={() => visible = !visible}
  >
    <h3 class="text-base flex-1">{title}</h3>
    <i class="fa {visible ? 'fa-caret-up text-primary' : 'fa-caret-right'}"></i>
  </div>
  {#if visible}
    <div class="bg-primary p-6 article" transition:slide class:hidden>
      <slot/>
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>
```

It works, but this is a bit tricky and looks more like a workaround to me.

Also, it produces some tiny glitch on page load, like the icon appeared as "open" before rolling back immediately.

Can I achieve it a smarter way?

Comment: Maybe try switching around your `true`s and `false`s (to get rid of the blip)? Initialize them to `false`, then do `if typeof  window === 'undefined'` and set them to `true`.

Comment: About which boolean? The goal is to simplify the code and get rid of two booleans, basically.

Comment: See if this might work: `export let visible = false; typeof window === 'undefined' && (visible = true)`

Comment: I can't do it like that, because I will never see the content with SSR. I need the content to be present for CLI crawl and SEO.

Comment: Try it in one line: `export let visible = typeof window === 'undefined'`